# Настройка плагина SNAP для wordpress

Tags: wordpress, плагин, wp-plugin

Поставил плагин NextScripts (SNAP) для автопостинга в Твитер новостей с сайта. Нужно чтобы он фото постил.

Есть две проблемы:

1. Постит не все новости с фото.
2. Там где есть фото, зачем то указывает ссылку на хранилище фото.

Как можно исправить? Может кто то сталкивался.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В настройках плагина нашел 4 пункта, которые касаются вывода:

1. Выводить с фото (если выкл, то фото не выводятся)
2. Проверять фото (есть вкл, то фото не выводятся)
3. Расширенный поиск фото (поидее выводит первое фото из статьи)
4. Формат вывода (`%title% %content% %URL%`)

Answer (score 1):

Ничего этого не надо. Вот настройки [image: Настройки тви в плагине SNAP]

Вот результат: [Тви-лента](https://twitter.com/WTE_Intl)

Секрет в том, что каждая запись блога WordPress обязательно должна иметь featured image. Тогда все работает.